# Quesion regarding pointers in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
void fun1(char *s1, char *s2) {
     char *temp;
     temp = s1;
     s1 = s2;
     s2 = temp;
}

int main () {
     char *str1 = "Hello", *str2 = "there!"
     fun1(str1, str2);
     printf("%s %s", str1, str2);
     return 0;
}
```

Given the code above, from my understand we pass the pointers by value, so if for example the values are str1 = 1000, str2 = 2000, fun1 switches them around, so str1 = 2000, str2 = 1000.
So when we are trying to print them, we should get "there! Hello", but the answers says that it prints "Hello there!" and I don't understand why.. by switching them around str1's value should be the memory adress of the first character of "there!" and str2 of the first character of "Hello"..
I feel like I'm missing something important..

Comment: You function `fun1` is swapping its copies of the pointers.  It is not swapping the pointed-to data, and it is not doing anything to the `str1` and `str2` pointers in the caller.

Comment: "from my understand we pass the pointers by value" - you answer your own question in the first sentence.

Comment: The variables in the function are not the same as the variables in `main`

Comment: so whenever we pass by value we create a copy of the passed down arguements? that is, new copies which have their own location in memory and have no connection once so ever with the original variables?

Comment: That is a good definition of pass-by-value.

Comment: @MathCurious: Yes, `s1` and `s2` are different objects from `str1` and `str2`; the value of `str1` is copied to `s1`, the value of `str2` is copied to `s2`.  Any changes to `s1` and `s2` do not affect the values of `str1` or `str2`.  So `s1` and `s2` need to be *pointers to* `str1` and `str2` with type `char **`; in the body of `swap` you read and write to `*s1` and `*s2`, and the arguments to `swap` need to be `&str1` and `&str2`.

Answer (score 2):

The pointers are *passed by value*, so switching values of `s1` and `s2` will not affect `str1` and `str2`.

If you want functions modify what caller specifies, you should pass pointers to what should be modified like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void fun1(char **s1, char **s2) {
     char *temp;
     temp = *s1;
     *s1 = *s2;
     *s2 = temp;
}

int main (void) {
     char *str1 = "Hello", *str2 = "there!"
     fun1(&str1, &str2);
     printf("%s %s", str1, str2);
     return 0;
}
```